# KWIC command throws Error: object 'docname' not found

Tags: r, shiny, quanteda

I have created a dashboard using R-shiny. User will enter a word , it gets passed to KWIC command and output is displayed as tables in the main panel.

If the word exists it will show the table, if not it will throw the appropriate error as defined in validate block. But when i'm passing word "abcdef" it throws *Error: object 'docname' not found.* i don't know what wrong i'm doing here.

```
table1 <- eventReactive((input$submit_kwic),
subset(kwic(corpus1, pattern = c(input$word1), case_insensitive = TRUE, window = 20), select = c(docname, pre, keyword, post)))
```

```
output$tab1 <- renderTable({

    if (input$submit_kwic== 0){return()}      
    else{
      isolate({
        validate(
          need(input$word1 !='',"No table output shown as word 1 is not supplied"),
          need(sum(grepl(input$word1, x = attr(tokens_wo_stp, "types"))) >= 1,"Word does not exist in vocabulary, try another word!")
        )
        table1()
      })
    }}, striped = TRUE, hover = TRUE, bordered = TRUE)
```

[image: Snippet shows the error]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your error. I believe *Error: object 'docname' not found* indicates that `subset()` is not using non-standarad evaluation (for some reason) and is looking for an object named docname instead of recognizing that you want the column named docname. To play it safe, I would quote the column names.

Another problem that I ran into is that `quanteda` is trying to use its own subset method I think. You can use the subset method for `data.frame`s by converting the kwic object first. kwic objects are, as far as I know, regular `data.frame`s except the additional class "kwic". By wrapping the `kwic()` in `as.data.frame()` you force `R` to use the `data.frame` subset method, which does what you want.

Here is a possible solution, including reproducible data (you should always include reproducible data in your questions as it makes them easier to answer and understand).

```
library(quanteda)

corpus1 <- corpus(c("I have created a dashboard using R-shiny. User will enter a word , it gets passed to KWIC command and output is displayed as tables in the main panel."))

input <- data.frame(word1 = "dashboard",
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

subset(as.data.frame(kwic(corpus1, pattern = c(input$word1), 
                          case_insensitive = TRUE, 
                          window = 20)), 
       select = c("docname", "pre", "keyword", "post"))
```

I did not check the rest of your code since the `subset` line appears to be the source of your problem. But it's hard to say, since without the full shiny code, I can't reproduce your app.

Comment: Indeed subset line is creating problem. But i think there might be problem with my condition `sum(grepl("def", x = attr(tokens_wo_stp, "types"))) >= 1` because it shows **TRUE**  and there is no word "def" in **tokens_wo_stp**

Comment: I don't understand this function. What is `tokens_wo_stp`? If you want to test if `kwic` returns anything you can use `shiny::need(nrow(table1) > 0 , "Word does not exist in vocabulary, try another word!")` where `table1 ` is the output of the `subset` + `kwic` line.

Comment: `tokens_wo_stp` is tokenized version of my corpus which i should have mentioned earlier. If is use `need(nrow(table1) > 0` , it displays the `Word does not ...` everytime, even when the word is present in `tokens_wo_stp` .    When i was using `need(sum(grepl(input$word2, x = attr(tokens_w_stp, "types"))) >= 1,"Word does not exist in vocabulary, try another word!")` it basically tells you if occurrence of the word is 1 or more. If *True*, show the kwic output else throw error. But it was also detecting partially, for eg: it was detecting  "def" in "deficiency".

Comment: So i put boundary conditions, `grepl(pattern = paste("\\b", input$word2, "\\b", sep = ""), x = attr(tokens_w_stp, "types")` and now its running smoothly. No errors except the ones defined in validate-need block.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have removed columns from the kwic object with the call to `subset(x, select = ...)` and then in the `renderTable()` call, the line `table1()` returns the subsetted `kwic` object that invokes `kwic.print()`.  This method assumes that certain columns are present, such as `docname`, but they are not because you have removed them with the column subsetting (`subset()` call).

This should fix it: replace the line

```
        table1()
```

with

```
        print.data.frame(table1())
```

I filed an issue for this at https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/1665 and hopefully we will fix it soon so that this workaround is unnecessary.  (But this workaround should always work.)

Comment: Tried it but no success. What i'm wondering is why is it happening for certain words and not for all. As you can see, outputs of words 2 to 5 are fine. If i pass words "abcdef" or "def" in either of the 5 inputs, it throws 'docname' not found error. It shows an empty table if i remove the `select= c(.....)` from subset.

Comment: I took a guess but it was only a guess, without a reproducible example, I cannot diagnose your issue.